# Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/c]

Tags: spring

Using spring 3.0 version and added
       `xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"`
Still have error

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [resources/newSpringXMLConfig.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/c]
Offending resource: class path resource [resources/newSpringXMLConfig.xml]
```

Comment: Can you post your spring configuration, mainly the declaration part on the top?

Comment: xml file is==ion="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“p” ad “c” namespaces will not have a schema reference in the XML header. 
Ensure that you have enough jars added as part of configuration.

Maven configuration for the jar files

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: could you please let me know which jar required

Comment: If you use maven, the dependencies work. Or else download and add the jar files mentioned under artifactId tag to your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Add all required jars:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was using spring 3.0 and it was not able to find c schema. Just upgraded and worked fine.

Solution :
upgrade spring 3.0 to spring 3.1.1.RELEASE
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core